# How to merge Video.js buttons into one

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, video.js

Is there anyway to merge/group video.js option buttons into one option button ?

**Group buttons** (Quality selector / Audio Selector / Caption Selector) :
[image]

**Into one group button** (like this) :
[image]

Comment: can you provide a sandbox with what you have currently?

Comment: did you try creating your own button ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335278/how-to-create-customs-button-in-video-js

Comment: @ChiKaLiO I have audio selector , caption selector and quality selector and want to merge it like plyr.io video player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Menu(player, optionsopt)` class from the doc - https://docs.videojs.com/menu#addChild

> The Menu component is used to build popup menus, including subtitle and captions selection menus.

you can build your own popup menu and add other buttons to it.

Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/exception777/xsucrz1m/32/

It uses Menu class to create a quality menu and added options for multiple quality, you can use the same thing, just instead of quality, you will add your controls.

```
var VideoJsButtonClass = videojs.getComponent('MenuButton');
var VideoJsMenuClass = videojs.getComponent('Menu');
var VideoJsComponent = videojs.getComponent('Component');
var VideoJsMenuItemClass = videojs.getComponent('MenuItem');
var Dom = videojs.dom;

/**
 * Extend vjs button class for quality button.
 */
var QualityMenu = function (_VideoJsButtonClass) {
    inherits(QualityMenu, _VideoJsButtonClass);

    /**
     * Button constructor.
     *
     * @param {Player} player - videojs player instance
     */
    function QualityMenu(player) {
        classCallCheck(this, QualityMenu);
        return possibleConstructorReturn(this, _VideoJsButtonClass.call(this, player, {}));
    }

    /**
     * Creates button items.
     *
     * @return {Array} - Button items
     */
    QualityMenu.prototype.createItems = function createItems() {
        return [];
    };

    /**
     * Create the menu and add all items to it.
     *
     * @return {Menu}
     *         The constructed menu
     */
    QualityMenu.prototype.createMenu = function createMenu() {
        var menu = new VideoJsMenuClass(this.player_, { menuButton: this });

        this.hideThreshold_ = 0;

        this.items = this.createItems();

        if (this.items) {
            // Add menu items to the menu
            for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                menu.addItem(this.items[i]);
            }
        }

        return menu;
    };

    return QualityMenu;
}(VideoJsButtonClass);

var QualityMenuItem = function (_VideoJsMenuItemClass) {
    inherits(QualityMenuItem, _VideoJsMenuItemClass);

    /**
     * Menu item constructor.
     *
     * @param {Player} player - vjs player
     * @param {Object} item - Item object
     * @param {QualityMenu} qualityMenu - The containing button.
     * @param {HlsQualitySelectorPlugin} plugin - This plugin instance.
     */
    function QualityMenuItem(player, item, qualityMenu, plugin) {
        classCallCheck(this, QualityMenuItem);

        var _this = possibleConstructorReturn(this, _VideoJsMenuItemClass.call(this, player, {
            label: item.label,
            selectable: true,
            selected: item.selected || false
        }));

        _this.item = item;
        _this.qualityMenu = qualityMenu;
        _this.plugin = plugin;
        return _this;
    }

    /**
     * Click event for menu item.
     */
    QualityMenuItem.prototype.handleClick = function handleClick() {
        // Reset other menu items selected status.
        for (var i = 0; i < this.qualityMenu.items.length; ++i) {
            this.qualityMenu.items[i].selected(false);
        }
        
        // Set this menu item to selected, and set quality.
        this.plugin.setQuality(this.item);
        this.selected(true);
    };

    return QualityMenuItem;
}(VideoJsMenuItemClass);


var QualitySelectorPlugin = function () {
    function QualitySelectorPlugin(player, options) {
        this.player = player;
        this.qualityParams = this.getQualityParams(player.el().dataset.qualityParams);

        if (this.qualityParams.length > 0) {
            this.createQualityMenu();
            this.onAddQualityLevel();
        }
    }

    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.getQualityParams = function getQualityParams(qualityParams) { 
        qualityParams = [
            {quality: -1, level: -1, label: 'Auto'},
            {quality: 234, level: 0, label: '234p'},
            {quality: 360, level: 1, label: '360p'},
            {quality: 540, level: 2, label: '540p'},
            {quality: 720, level: 3, label: '720p'},
            {quality: 1080, level: 4, label: '1080p'},
        ];
        if (!(qualityParams.length > 0)) {
            return [];
        }

        qualityParams.sort(function (current, next) {
            if (current.quality < next.quality) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (current.quality > next.quality) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        return qualityParams; 
    };

    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.createQualityMenu = function createQualityMenu() {
        var player = this.player;

        this._qualityMenu = new QualityMenu(player);
        
        var placementIndex = player.controlBar.children().length - 2;
        var qualityMenuInstance = player.controlBar.addChild(this._qualityMenu, { componentClass: 'qualitySelector' }, placementIndex);

        qualityMenuInstance.addClass('vjs-quality-selector');
        qualityMenuInstance.menuButton_.$('.vjs-icon-placeholder').className += ' vjs-icon-quality';
        qualityMenuInstance.removeClass('vjs-hidden');
    };

    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.getQualityMenuItem = function getQualityMenuItem(item) {
        var player = this.player;

        return new QualityMenuItem(player, item, this._qualityMenu, this);
    };

    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.onAddQualityLevel = function onAddQualityLevel() {
        var _this = this;

        var player = this.player;
        var levels = this.qualityParams;
        var levelItems = [];

        var _loop = function _loop(i) {
            if (!levelItems.filter(function (_existingItem) {
                return _existingItem.item && _existingItem.item.level === levels[i].level;
            }).length) {
                var levelItem = _this.getQualityMenuItem.call(_this, {
                    label: levels[i].label,
                    level: levels[i].level,
                    quality: levels[i].quality,
                    selected: levels[i].level == -1 || false
                });

                levelItems.push(levelItem);
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; ++i) {
            _loop(i);
        }

        if (this._qualityMenu) {
            this._qualityMenu.createItems = function () {
                return levelItems;
            };
            this._qualityMenu.update();
        }
    };
    
    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.getHls = function getHls() {
        return this.player.tech({ IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true }).hls;
    };

    QualitySelectorPlugin.prototype.setQuality = function setQuality(qualityItem) {
        var player = this.player;
        this.getHls().representations().forEach(function(rep) {
           rep.enabled(rep.height === qualityItem.quality || qualityItem.quality === -1);
        });

        this._qualityMenu.unpressButton();
    };

    return QualitySelectorPlugin;
}();

/**
 * Function to invoke when the player is ready.
 *
 * This is a great place for your plugin to initialize itself. When this
 * function is called, the player will have its DOM and child components
 * in place.
 *
 * @function onPlayerReady
 * @param    {Player} player
 *           A Video.js player object.
 *
 * @param    {Object} [options={}]
 *           A plain object containing options for the plugin.
 */

var onPlayerReady = function onPlayerReady(player, options) {
        player.addClass('vjs-quality-selector');
        player.qualitySelector = new QualitySelectorPlugin(player, options);
};

/**
 * A video.js plugin.
 *
 * In the plugin function, the value of `this` is a video.js `Player`
 * instance. You cannot rely on the player being in a "ready" state here,
 * depending on how the plugin is invoked. This may or may not be important
 * to you; if not, remove the wait for "ready"!
 *
 * @function qualitySelector
 * @param    {Object} [options={}]
 *           An object of options left to the plugin author to define.
 */


var qualitySelector = function qualitySelector(options) {
    var _this = this;

    this.ready(function () {
    onPlayerReady(_this, videojs.mergeOptions(defaults, options));
    });
}; // Register the plugin with video.js.

registerPlugin('qualitySelector', qualitySelector); // Include the version number.

qualitySelector.VERSION = version;

return qualitySelector;

 }));
```

...

Also, I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-group-play package, check it out, might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I have audio , caption and quality selector and want to merge them into a button group exactly what plyr.io video player do